# PDO Connection fails

Tags: pdo

This is my database connection code when i'm not going to put it inside a  function within the class it works but if its inside function it doesn't any idea?

```
class DBConnection {

private $connection;

function __construct(){
  $this->open_connection();
}

public static function open_connection(){

  try {
      $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=practice','root','');
      $connection->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
      $connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
      $connection->exec("SET character_set_server=utf8");
      $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      return $connection;

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMesage());

  }

}

}// class ends
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in your code is you use a static function to return the connection and your constructor not assign to you private variable

first solution with private $connection :

```
class DBConnection {

private $connection;

function __construct(){
  $this->connection = $this->open_connection();
}

public static function open_connection(){

  try {
      $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=practice','root','');
      $connection->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
      $connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
      $connection->exec("SET character_set_server=utf8");
      $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      return $connection;

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMesage());

  }

}
```

seconde with connection static

```
class DBConnection {

private static $connection = null;

function __construct(){
  if (self::$connection == null) 
        $this->open_connection();
}

public static function open_connection(){

  try {
      self::$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=practice','root','');
      self::$connection->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
      self::$connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
      self::$connection->exec("SET character_set_server=utf8");
      self::$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMesage());

  }

}
```

I hope to help you.

Comment: i tried your code sir but still it doesn't work..does pdo have compatability issues with xampp?my original code when i pasted it in my old database connection file in a different project it works..but when i make a new one I using that code it doesn't..i tried yours still it doesn't in windows 8 sometimes it worked(once) dn fails..im working now on win 7 still it fails..

Comment: You have uncomment  `extension=pdo.so` and  `extension=pdo_mysql.so` in your `php.ini` ? Or activate with xamp the pdo extension ? 
Use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to verify if pdo is enabled

Comment: I'm sorry, I never use xampp but on windows you need to enable pdo.dll and pdo_mysql.dll or php_pdo.dll and php_pdo_mysql.dll.